# Arduino, delay in a task scheduler

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, interrupt, scheduler

I'm currently stuck on a problem, which involves a program using a task scheduler and a task using a delay.

A task is running the following code:

```
// Some function
delay(_speedVar);
// Some function
delay(_speedVar);
// End of task.
```

Where as I have another task, just polling for information from the UART, so set the value of _speedVar.

```
// Uart task
if(Serial.available())
{
  _speedVar = Serial.read();
}
// End of task
```

My problem is, that if speedVar is set to a high value, let's say 10 seconds, the task doing some function and having a delay of (_speedVar), needs to be interrupted somehow, and started over with the new _speedVar value.

There's actually no flexibility in the Task Scheduler I'm using. It only allows me to create and destroy tasks. I'm yet to find one that have more functions and that works probably, so I'm stuck with this one for now

Only idea to a solution, would be the use of an interrupt, but I'm unsure how to get this implemented correctly when using a task scheduler.

All programming is done in C++ using Arduino's Sketch tool. Programming unit is an Arduino Uno.

Comment: You say C/C++ but tagged only C - C or C++ - it can't be both.

Comment: Strictly symbols with an underscore prefix are reserved for use by the compiler and its standard library implementation.

Comment: Use a multitasking OS with creedence and stop polling for stuff.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification. What I mean with c/c++, was the implementation of C++ classes in an embedded C program in Arduino. 

For the OS, I've been using http://www.meatandnetworking.com/code/introducing-arduino-simple-task-scheduler/ to schedule tasks. 

What I was hoping for, is some function, sort of what you have in FreeRTOS, with a taskPause function. Basically puts the task in the blocked state for x ms, where it is then moved back in the ready queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the scheduler is cooperative and these fragments of code you have posted are somehow called in some "big-loop", then, most non-trivial tasks would typically be implemented as state-machines.  Given:

```
class cElapsedTime
{
    cElapsedTime()
    {
       zero() ; 
    }

    void zero()
    {
        timestamp = millis() ;
    }

    bool time()
    {
        return millis() - m_timestamp ;
    }
} ;

enum
{
    STATE_A,
    STATE_B
}  state = STATE_A;

cElapsedTime control_task_delay ;
```

Then toggle between two states to execute different code blocks after each delay period.  By continuously comparing the elapsed time with the *current* value of `_speedVar`, the delay can be changed at any time. If `_speedVar` changed from 10 seconds to 5, and elapsed time is 7 seconds, the delayed code will be executed immediatly; if the time is extended, so will the delay:

```
if( control_task_delay.time() >= _speedVar )
{
    switch( state )
    {
        case STATE_A :
            // Some function

            control_task_delay.zero()      // Restart delay
            state = STATE_B ;              // Next state
        break ;

        case STATE_B :
            // Some function

            control_task_delay.zero()      // Restart delay
            state = STATE_A ;              // Next state
        break ;
    }
}
```

It is not clear in your code fragment that the first `// Some function` is not identical to the second; perhaps `// Some other function` would have clarified? However if they were in fact identical then the code would be simply:

```
if( control_task_delay.time() >= _speedVar )
{
    // Some function

    control_task_delay.zero()      // Restart delay
}
```

You can see that it is the same principle you have applied to your UART polling task - using a non-blocking test.  That said, there is perhaps no need for separate tasks in any case; you could have:

```
if( Serial.available() )
{
    _speedVar = Serial.read();
}

if( control_task_delay.time() >= _speedVar )
{
    switch( state )
    {
        case STATE_A :
            // Some function

            control_task_delay.zero()      // Restart delay
            state = STATE_B ;              // Next state
        break ;

        case STATE_B :
            // Some function

            control_task_delay.zero()      // Restart delay
            state = STATE_A ;              // Next state
        break ;
    }
}
```

It is not clear in your code fragment that the first `// Some function` is not identical to the second; perhaps `// Some other function` would have clarified? However if they were in fact identical then the code would be simply:

```
if( control_task_delay.time() >= _speedVar )
{
    // Some function

    control_task_delay.zero()      // Restart delay
}

if( control_task_delay.time() >= _speedVar )
{
    switch( state )
    {
        case STATE_A :
            // Some function

            control_task_delay.zero()      // Restart delay
            state = STATE_B ;              // Next state
        break ;

        case STATE_B :
            // Some function

            control_task_delay.zero()      // Restart delay
            state = STATE_A ;              // Next state
        break ;
    }
}
```

It is hard to see what the "scheduler" is achieving in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.

Sorry for the missing description. It is two seperate functions that are used. Definitely going to try your solution and return with an answer :)

But the use of a scheduler could be objected against in this case. However, I'm running 3 tasks total. One doing the delay, which you just gave a possible solution to. Another task running a FSM, keeping track on the UART input, on any change on the FSM. The last is saved for a sensor reading, yet to be implemented.

Comment: Tried your solution and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: @user3008529 : You are welcome.  I appreciate that you are new to StackOverflow, but if this turns out to be an acceptable answer, you might like to select it as accepted.  You can always deselect it later if a better answer is posted.

Comment: I accepted your answer as accepted. Don't see the reason for an alternative answer in such a small program as this one.

Comment: @user3008529 : Well this was my second answer - I may have a better one yet ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A Cooperative task scheduler's tasks cannot include delays or blocking IO operations.
Instead you need to calculate ticks to match the time you need (On arduino I guess you can use http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/millis )

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Looked into that solution and what I encounter using a timer for with millis() to compare with, is that the Task is now stalling the other tasks, which make the use of a task scheduler rather negligible :)

Comment: @user3008529 : HLL did not offer a solution using `milis()`, he merely alluded to one. The fact that *your solution* did not work does not mean that there is not a solution using it, merely that yours did not work. Are we to assume then that your scheduler *is* cooperative? That would have been useful information to include in your question.  Not only can you not use blocking calls in cooperative scheduling, you cannot use *busy-wait* loops.